# arc land pushes to repo, but in Phabricator still shown as accepted

Tags: git, phabricator

I've setup Phabricator for a repo I'm hosting on bitbucket.  arc diff works as expected.  And arc land pushes the diff into the repository correctly.  But the diff still is shown as 'accepted' not as 'pushed' or 'landed' in the differential page.

I've looked through the documentation, but don't see what additional steps I need...let me know if I didn't provide enough information.

Answer (score 0):

In Diffusion, verify the Repo that you are tracking has "Autoclose" set to "On" under Actions.

Comment: Thanks.  Went to the repo page and saw that 'initializing Working Copy' is failing.  Probably need to handle permission issues on my end.